SystemVerilog When instantiating a module how can I connect an output to each wire of a multidimensional bus
Say I have the multidimensional bus
wire logic [7:0]example_bus[60] [16][4];

and a module has the output
output logic [7:0]example_out[16][4];

How would I assign example_out to all 60 wires in example_bus?
I know how to assign it to individual wires.
example_mod example_mod1(
.example_out(example_bus[0]));

But I can't work out how to assign the output to the whole bus.
I have considered using a seperate assignment but I find that usually causes timing problems.

You can use an assigment pattern to make the assigments simpler
  wire logic [7:0] example_bus[60] [16][4];
  wire logic [7:0] example_temp [16][4];
  
  example_mod example_mod1(
    .example_out(example_temp)
                  );
  assign example_bus = '{default:example_temp};

But that won't change the fact that each wire of example_out fans out to 60 wires in example_bus. It is effectively the same as
for(genvar i=0;i<60;i++) begin
        assign example_bus[i] = example_temp;
end


Thanks for the response! Unfortunately while quartus can compile this, modelsim throws an error
"Questa has encountered an unexpected internal error: ../../src/vlog/vgendecl.c(7760). Please contact Questa support at http://supportnet.mentor.com/"
So I can't check if this actually fixed my problem.

You must have an old version. I tested this on Questa myself. https://edaplayground.com/x/A7jL

Unfortunately I don't have a license and the sslc is a nightmare so I can't use Questa

@Lupushonora, updated my answer. If that creates a timing issue, you have a very different problem.

thanks! I had more or less worked that out on my own but I had hoped not to have to use it as the module I am working on is very complex and relies on multiple timers and clocks so making sure things happen in the right order is a nightmare. Luckily in this case I was just being dense, what I was trying to do made no sense and the problem I was trying to solve could actually be fixed in the earlier module.
